# Unity Gradle build suddenly started failing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

The only change I made was the Package name of the project. 2 days ago I was able to build with gradle no problem what so ever. I wonder what happened? Here is error message from the console :

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity 2017.2.0b10\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Note: there were 11 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: com.alipay.android.phone.mrpc.core.j: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory getHttpSocketFactory(int,android.net.SSLSessionCache)' in library class android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue? I ran into it today

Comment: Sadly no.. I switched to using the internal build system and that worked. after reinstalling java, android sdk and jdk.